# Amazon SQS send message attributes in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I need to implement sending messages to SQS with attributes.
The body of the message is uploading fine, but I have problem with attributes.
Message Attributes require Associative array with Name of the Attribute, Data Type, and Value. I got this kind of error :

AWS HTTP error: Client error: 400 InvalidParameterValue (client): The request must contain non-empty message attribute name.

the function for sending messages:

```
public function uploadMessage(DataTransferObjectInterface $dataTransferObject)
{

    $command = $this->client->getCommand(
        'SendMessage',
        [
            'QueueUrl' => $this->queueUrl->value(),
            'MessageBody' => $dataTransferObject->getBody()->value(),
            'MessageAttributes' => $dataTransferObject->getAttributes(),

        ]
    );

    $this->client->execute($command);

}
```

function getAttributes() returns $attributes array

& the test where I run the code

```
   $attributes = [
   'TestName' =>
            [
            'Name'=>'test',
            'DataType' => 'string',
            'Value' => 'string',

        ]
    ];
    $age = array("Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "9", "Joe" => "43");
    $json = json_encode($age);
    $body = Json::get($json);

    $dto = new DataTransferObject($attributes, $body);

    $uploader = new SQSManager($sqsClient, $queueUrl);
    $uploader->uploadMessage($dto);
```

How does the $attributes array should look like?

Comment: have you tried with this format from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sqs.SqsClient.html#_sendMessage ?

Also witch version are you using?

Comment: Yes, It's not working. I am using sdk 3.0 version.

Comment: I’ve got the very same problem. This seems to be either a bug in AWS’ PHP SDK or a faulty documentation of MessageAttributes. Haven’t found a solution, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [fix for this bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/694) is built into version 3.2.1 and greater.

Additionally, your message attributes array doesn't match the format shown in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html#shape-messageattributevalue). Your attributes should look like this:

```
$attributes = [
    '<attribute name>' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => '<attribute value>',
    ],
];
```

Comment: You’re right. His message array is invalid. However, I’m using the correct notation like in your answer and the error is still the same: "non-empty message attribute name".

Comment: Ah, I see. A fix went out in yesterday's release, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: There needs to be an example like this on the official docs; they're very confusing.

Comment: Agreed that their syntax is confusing. Here is another [example from their docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish)

Comment: @Elte156 your referenced page is for SNS, not SQS.